# ¿Como mantener sesión iniciada utilizando Firebase en Android?

Tags: android, firebase

Utilizo firebase para el inicio de sesión de un usuario con email y contraseña, todo funciona bien, solo que necesito que al cerrar la app y volver a abrirla, la sesión siga abierta. Leí que podría utilizar SharedPreferences pero no encuentro una solución real a lo que quiero hacer.
Esta es mi función para inicializar Firebase en mi aplicación

```
private void inicialize() {
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged - Logueado");

            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged - Cerro sesion");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Esta función la utiliza para hacer el inicio de sesión

```
  private void signIn(String email, String password) {
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Autenticacion correcta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Autenticacion incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Y en el onCreate de LoginActivity utilizo un botón que se encarga de realizar la función del logueo

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    etUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsuario);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    Button btnIngresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ingresar);
    Button btnAbrirCrearCuenta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbrirCrearCuenta);

    //Inicializamos firebase
    inicialize();

    //Al presionar Boton de Ingresar se ejecuta la funcion de Firebase
    btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Validamos los inputs
            String email = etUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Ingrese un usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Ingrese una contrasena", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            signIn(etUsuario.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

Como podría guardar los datos del usuario logueado y que al abrir de nuevo la aplicación (siempre y cuando no haya dado Cerrar Sesión), pueda abrir directamente mi MainActivity sin tener que introducir los datos de nuevo.

Comment: efectivamente en este caso para mantener la sesión activa es recomendable el uso del SharedPreferences https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=es-419 y ese concepto basicamente consiste en guardar una clave-valor.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario usar `SharedPreferences`, simplemente en tu método `inicialize`, en la parte de:

```
 if (firebaseUser != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged - Logueado");
```

Ahí coloca un `Intent` hacia tu siguiente actividad.